# Can't use PPPoE connection on boot , until 30+ seconds later

Tags: windows

When I boot my Windows XP , it's fast. WHen everything is done , I see no more blinking of the HDD indicator. I try to use the PPPoE connection (I create a shortcut on desktop) , it's in-responsive. But waiting for like 30 seconds , it shows up

How should I fix it ?

**UPDATE**

Laptop: Thinkpad X220 4290-JY1

I have both ethernet card and a wireless card , I set static IP/netmask for the ethernet card , but sometimes I still see the symbol (the one looking for an ip address) on system tray.

Also I installed both VirtualBox and VMware , three extra virtual ethernet cards

It happens no matter the cable is connected or not. I disabled wireless devices with the switch on laptop

Comment: What does your Ethernet cable connect to on the other end? Is it a switch? And if so, what make/model?

Comment: ...and what make/model motherboard do you have? Can you communicate with your router in that time?

Comment: This is normal. XP was the first Microsoft OS to allow you access to the desktop before all services were started up. My recommendation is to wait those 30 seconds before logging in, after a reboot.

Comment: It's really wired , I found the culprit was Visual Studio 2010's installation. I removed .NET Framework 4 Client Profile and the extend package , the stuck time reduced to 5~10 seconds